# Requests HTML JavaScript hidden input

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, hidden, python-requests-html

trying to get the fingerprint value to feed into automated login via request-html:

```
# import HTMLSession from requests_html
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time

# create an HTML Session object
session = HTMLSession()

# Use the object above to connect to needed webpage
resp = session.get("https://slatehouse.appfolio.com/users/sign_in")

# Run JavaScript code on webpage
resp.html.render()

sel = '#fingerprint' 
fp = resp.html.find(sel)

print(fp)
```

output of the code:

```
[<Element 'input' type='hidden' name='fingerprint' id='fingerprint'>]
```

There is no value key, which I think is generated by javascript (thought rendering would allow it to be picked out)

Answer (score 0):

Having executed the JS of the web page in real browser I got:

```
<form class="form form--stacked form--full-width" id="new_user" data-type="html" 
novalidate="novalidate" action="/users/sign_in" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input 
type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" 
value="Du0TCAO+OjBXO6wYTkzlnl8N3d+n7Ls/giLYFxqb2EAQzshbYqs3Ngv3LdA==" />
<input type="hidden" name="fingerprint" id="fingerprint">
<input type="hidden" name="nfo" id="nfo">
```

The *input* has indeed **no value attr**. (after JS rendering)... So, my guess is that value you need is in a preceeding input:

```
value="Du0TCAO+OjBXO6wYTkzlnl8N3d+n7L...LYFxqb2EAQzshbYqs3Ngv3LdA=="
```

Answer (score 0):

just add blank JS code to render which will start when document ready and all on-page-js has completed.

```
...

resp.html.render(script="$(function() {return;});", reload=True)

...
```

and fp will looks like this:

```
[<Element 'input' type='hidden' name='fingerprint' id='fingerprint' value='14f7ac0c6b353f5280ab82837cef07a0'>]
```